# To bring the IE window in front of the Screen

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I am creating new IE browser instance dynamically, and opening a aspx page from there. Everything works fine , but the  browser is not popping in the Front of the screen .Able to see the Aspx page in the task bar when I click it from there  it comes to the Front . How to bring that page  in front of all the Screen as soon as IE is created.

I have pasted the code I used to create new IE instance.

```
public class IEInstance
{
    public SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE1;
    public void IEInstanceCls(string check)
    {
        IE1 = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
        object Empty = 0;
        string urlpath = " ";            
        urlpath = "http://localhost/TestPage.aspx?";         
        object URL = urlpath;
        IE1.Top = 260;
        IE1.Left = 900;
        IE1.Width = 390;
        IE1.Height = 460;
        IE1.StatusBar = false;
        IE1.ToolBar = 0;
        IE1.MenuBar = false;
        IE1.Visible = true;
        IE1.Navigate2(ref URL, ref Empty, ref Empty, ref Empty, ref Empty);
    }
}
```

Help me to solve this problem.

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

The Internet explorer object has an HWND property, which is the handle to a window. You can use that to bring the window to the front like:

```
    SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)IE1.HWND);
```

You'll need to import SetForgroundWindow windows API like this near the top of your file.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```